# css tables: how to display alternately first and last columns in a "abba" pattern on mobile?

Tags: css, cell, css-tables

I am new here.
I am banging my heads on the keyboard as I spent the last 2 hours trying to solve this problem:

ASSETS: I have a page where I list services using an image on the left, and text on the right. Except... the following service has text on the left and image on the right, so the page looks a little bit like a chequer board. IMAGE-TEXT / TEXT-IMAGE / IMAGE-TEXT.. you get the idea. I used tables to do that. one table and one row per service, two columns for each row.

This is great on desktop; the problem is that when on mobile, my trusty responsive tables act this way: they always put the left column on top of the right column, ignoring the content. The result is that I have IMAGE then TEXT than TEXT then IMAGE etc.., which is confusing when scrolling down on mobiles. We don't know what image relates to what because you would expect a different behaviour: you would want to see IMAGE, then TEXT, then IMAGE, then TEXT etc...

I haven't found any solution to this on the web, possibly because I can't synthesise properly my question in Google! So I thought I asked you. Please any comment and approach to this kind of problem is welcome!

Here's my CSS and HTML:

```css
section-services {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: inherit;
}
.row-services {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.col-left-services, .col-right-services {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.col-left-services {
padding-right: 10px;
}
.col-right-services {
padding-left:10px;
}
.content-services {

}

@media all and (max-width: 800px){
 section-services{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
 }
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px){
 .row-services,
 .col-left-services,
 .col-right-services,
 .col-left-services:before,
 .col-right-services:before{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
 }
}
```

```html
<section-services>
<div class="row-services">
<div class="col-left-services">
<div class="content-services">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">RED FERRARI</h2>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed haec quidem liberius ab eo dicuntur et saepius. Plane idem, inquit, et maxima quidem, qua fieri nulla maior potest.
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-right-services">
<div class="content-services">
<img src="http://buyersguide.caranddriver.com/media/assets/submodel/6873.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section-services>

<section-services>
<div class="row-services">
<div class="col-left-services">
<div class="content-services">
<img src="http://buyersguide.caranddriver.com/media/assets/submodel/6866.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-right-services">
<div class="content-services">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">YELLOW FERRARI</h2>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed haec quidem liberius ab eo dicuntur et saepius. Plane idem, inquit, et maxima quidem, qua fieri nulla maior potest.
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section-services>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this is to use `display: flex`.
Display your DIVs in flex mode and add a class to the second paragraph to force it to the top, like this:

```css
section-services {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: inherit;
}
.row-services {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.col-left-services, .col-right-services {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.col-left-services {
 padding-right: 10px;
}

.col-right-services {
padding-left:10px;
}

.content-services {

}

@media all and (max-width: 800px){
 section-services{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
 }
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px){
 .row-services,
 .col-left-services,
 .col-right-services,
 .col-left-services:before,
 .col-right-services:before {
  display:flex;
  -webkit-display:flex;
  -moz-display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
 }

 .col-floated {
  order: -1;
  -webkit-order: -1;
  -moz-order: -1;
 }

}
```

```html
<section-services>
 <div class="row-services">
  <div class="col-left-services">
   <div class="content-services">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">RED FERRARI</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed haec quidem liberius ab eo dicuntur et saepius. Plane idem, inquit, et maxima quidem, qua fieri nulla maior potest.
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right-services">
   <div class="content-services">
    <img src="http://buyersguide.caranddriver.com/media/assets/submodel/6873.jpg" />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section-services>

<section-services>
 <div class="row-services">
  <div class="col-left-services">
   <div class="content-services">
    <img src="http://buyersguide.caranddriver.com/media/assets/submodel/6866.jpg" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right-services col-floated">
   <div class="content-services">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">YELLOW FERRARI</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed haec quidem liberius ab eo dicuntur et saepius. Plane idem, inquit, et maxima quidem, qua fieri nulla maior potest.
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section-services>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Roberto for your take on this, will check it soon!

Comment: Roberto, this is a sleek hack and it works perfectly! Love your solution, thank you! PG